# Including manifest file in a UWP application in Visual Studio

Tags: uwp, manifest

I am using Visual Studio to generate a package for your desktop app, my desktop app has a manifest file named xxx.exe.manifest, I copied this file into the package like dll files, but it cannot work, dlls or com ponents defined in manifest can not work. Any one meets the same problem? Thanks.

Following is part content of my manifest file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity name="NFD" type="win32" version="18.0.0.0"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <file name="FileDialog.dll">
    <comClass clsid="{4BF4CC1F-33B0-4B43-9676-F7C98734F6CE}" threadingModel="Apartment" progid="FileDialogOl0.FileDlg.1" description="FileDlg Class">
      <progid>FileDialogOl0.FileDlg</progid>
    </comClass>
  </file>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Please share the content of the manifest and clarify what exactly fails, incl. errors message etc.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT manifest content is added, this manifest is for original desktop application, can this manifest work in the package?

Comment: After copy the manifest file in package, the UI shows same as without "Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls", the filedlg can not show, the com object cannot be created."

Comment: How are you creating the package? If the manifest is configured as an extra file, instead of embedded in the assembly, it should be copied automatically.

Comment: @rido, I created the package by Visual Studio Packaging Project, I've copied the manifest, but it has no use.